# mvc 5 error handling not working after third folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 app and with custom errors defined in `web.config`:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect" defaultRedirect="~/Errors/GeneralError">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Errors/ServerError" />
</customErrors>
```

if I type a none existing url it will handle it just fine as long as it is 3 levels/folders maximum. I also have Elmah installed and it will log the error. On the other hand, if I try accessing a none existing url with 4 or more levels/folders, the error will not be handled. It won't redirect to the custom error page, or the default error page. Instead, it will return a blank page with a 404 header. meaning:

- `website.com/blahblah`
- `website.com/a/blahblah`
- `website.com/a/b/blahblah`

will be handled, but `website.com/a/b/c/blahblah` and above won't. Additionally, I have some pages with 4 or more folders, and they work fine. This problem occurs on local production computer and on the published site on Azure. Anyone has an insight of why?

### Solution

Thanks to @Nicholas Patton's link I made these chages:

---

(1) I removed customErrors completely

---

(2) added this to `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Errors/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="403"/>
  <error statusCode="403" path="/Errors/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="500"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Errors/ServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

---

(3) In contrary to the article's suggestion using `.aspx` files I used regular actions in MVC. For example, in controller `Error` I used `NotFound` action like so:

```
[Route("Errors/NotFound")]
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return View("Error404");
}
```

There are a few differences now. the 404 page will not be redirect to `Error/NotFound?aspxerrorpath=/errorURL/a/b/c` it will simply show the custom error page in the original link without redirection. If you still want the `aspxerrorpath` value you can simply get the URL in the action like this:

```
[Route("Errors/NotFound")]
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    string aspxerrorpath = Request.RawUrl;
    // do whatever with aspxerrorpath 

    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return View("Error404");
}
```

Nonetheless, Elmah still doesn't log 404 errors above 3 folders. But this is a different issue for a new question.

Comment: Could you post what routes you have configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this:
https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging

From the link above:

> ...what if someone navigates to a URL which isn't handled by ASP.NET?
>   For example try navigating to http://{your-website}/a/b/c/d/e/f/g. The
>   route is not mapped to ASP.NET and therefore the Application_Error
>   event will not be raised.

This is a really great tutorial if you really want your custom error pages to be beefy. :)