# Elmah not logging 404 errors after third folder, and 403 errors at all

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah

Continuing my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423379/mvc-5-error-handling-not-working-after-third-folder/37473743#37473743), I handle custom errors in my mvc5 app using:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Errors/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="403"/>
      <error statusCode="403" path="/Errors/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="500"/>
      <error statusCode="500" path="/Errors/ServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  ...
  </system.webServer>
```

This enabled me to show custom 404 error page after the 3rd folder (e.g. site.com/a/b/c/nothing-here). Yet, Elmah is not logging these errors. This is also true for 403 errors. So My questions are:

1. is there a way to make Elmah handle all server errors regardless of
   being thrown by the mvc app itself?
2. if not, since `/Errors/NotFound` is successfully executed, I can add a log from that action. is there a way to tell if Elmah already handled this error (or was it thrown by the mvc app)?